# SignalR hubs Invoke deadlock

Tags: c#, signalr, signalr-hub

I have some `hubProxy.Invoke("Method", param)` methods which are executing asynchronously. All of them calling the same method but with different args. The problem is that all of them executing properly on some PCs but another faces problem that only first method call is executed while others are executing forever.
Method looks like

```
if (!connectingTask.IsCompleted)
{
  logger.Debug("awaiting for SignalR connection");
  await connectingtTask;
  logger.Debug("SignalR connected");
}
await hubProxy.Invoke("MethodName", args);
logger.Debug("MethodName invoked");
```

Where `connectingTask = Connection.Start();` and `Connection` is a HubConnection instance.

When all methods (2, for example) are executed output looks like

```
Method 1: awaiting for SignalR connection
Method 2: awaiting for SignalR connection

Method 1: SignalR connected
Method 1: MethodName invoked

Method 2: SignalR connected
Method 2: MethodName invoked
```

And when only first method is executed output looks like

```
Method 1: awaiting for SignalR connection
Method 2: awaiting for SignalR connection

Method 1: SignalR connected
Method 2: SignalR connected

Method 1: MethodName invoked
```

And `Method 2` is deadlocked.
There is no blocks in the `Connection.StateChanged` callback and no awits after `Invoke()` methods.
So what am I doing wrong and how to Invoke the same method with different args asynchronously properly? Should I have some queue or something?

**Edit**  Or can it be because I'm sending `Invoke` after `await connectionTask`? Can't check it now because on my PC everything works fine. Link:

https://forums.asp.net/t/2024936.aspx?C+Client+Hangs+Deadlocks+Never+Returns

**Edit** And if relates the method on my hub I invoke has `Task` return type.

**Edit**
Here is my hub method:

```
public Task Attach(string groupName)
{
    return Groups.Add(Context.ConnectionId, groupName);
}
```

I'm not able to turn on tracing because on my PC usually all right but once I was able to recreate same issue. Not  remember how, I'll try to find later but the problem is that I'm not receiving answer when invoking hubs Attach method which is simply attaches user to group. So now instead of `await hubProxy.Invoke("Attach", groupName)` I'm using `hubProxy.Invoke("Attach", groupName)`. Can't understand why my first invokation is always successfull and I see some answer in trace but after that all invokations of the same method fails. But if I wait for some time (about 10+ seconds) and Invoke this method I'm again getting response. So looks like I'm able to Invoke hubs method only once per ~10 sec.

I'll try to recreate this issue again and add full trace.

Comment: Turn on tracing. Show more code - what you have is not enough to tell what may be going on.

Comment: @Pawel done. I'll add some more info like tracing later (1 or 4 days).

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using

```
await hubProxy.Invoke("MethodName", args);
```

try

```
hubProxy.Invoke("MethodName", args).Wait(500);
```

or whatever timeout you would like

I had the same issue and waiting seemed to have fixed it, I know await is the preferred method, but sometimes SignalR doesn't return properly

Comment: Yes, now I'm using just Invoke and that's works just fine but I really should be shure that user attached to group properly.